# How to align text boxes in a straight line in M.s. word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Suppose I have five text boxes(Insert > Text > TextBox > Draw a Text Box) in word document.

Suppose there is a line on the page. Each box should be on that line. So these boxes look like they are on a straight line
Current my Text boxes (Insert > Text > TextBox > Draw a Text Box)

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZb2G.jpg)

[What I want to achieve?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfx11.jpg)

How can I align these text boxes (Insert > Text > TextBox > Draw a Text Box) in a straight line in word. Is it possible?

**What have I tried?**

- I tried Select objects (Shift) > Format > arrange > Align > Distribute horizontally. These text boxes are not on straight line.

**Software details**

- Microsoft office 2013
- Windows 10

Comment: Distribute vertically?

Comment: Suppose there is a line on the page. Each box should be on that line. So these boxes look like they are on a straight line @DavidPostill

Comment: You need to "align bottom" (or "align to"), not distribute. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/align-pictures-shapes-wordart-and-other-objects-in-word-b8c4cada-67d5-446a-b7eb-ea22a44d3153

Comment: Note that the term "text box" is unfortunately ambiguous in Word. It appears you are using it to mean the graphical elements inserted using Insert > Text Box. For what purpose are you using five text boxes. You may want to look at Smart Art.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  What straight line are you referring to?  Can you update your example with what you're looking for as the end result?

Comment: Have you resolved this for yourself? I have an answer for you, and I’m sure others do as well ... but we are waiting for an acknowledgement from you.

Comment: Are the top border of the text boxes distributed on a horizontal line? If yes, please right click the text boxes one by one, chose "More Layout Options" > Absolute position under Vertical, set the same value below margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are four text boxes (Insert > Text > TextBox > Draw a Text Box) in your document in word.

As shown in this image

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1htI.jpg)

**Left click on one these text boxes (Insert > Text > TextBox > Draw a Text Box) + Press and hold Shift or Ctrl while you select the objects.  > Format > Arrange > align > Align Top**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBpwi.jpg)